# Find the value of $k$ if $AB=BA$

Tags: matrices, complex-multiplication

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 6\\
3 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$

$b=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & k
\end{bmatrix}$

Both are $2×2$ matrices. I have multiplied it but that's where I get stuck.

Comment: Multiply it out and solve for $k$. What are you stuck on?

Comment: To @Muhammad Ali: as suggested earlier by **anomaly** do multiplications, then use the definition for equality of two matrices of same size...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when $k=1$, $B$ is the identity matrix which satisfies $AB=BA$, and is the only $k$ value that satisfies $AB=BA$.